# How to return a particular pattern in a string using regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
let temp = 'Hi {{username}}, Your request with request id: {{requestId}} has been processed. Please contact your nearest shop.'
```

I want this array from the string:

`['userName', 'requestId']`

I know I have to somehow use regular expressions to achieve this but I can't figure out the pattern for achieving this.

**NOTE: This is just an example string and I want a more general approach to solve this problem coz the string may vary.**

Comment: whats about `{{(.*?)}}`. i do not have any experience with javascript, but on some languages it works

Comment: Output is coming with the brackets included. I don't want the brackets @D-E-N

Comment: You can simply add a capture group: `{{(.*?)}}`

Comment: Please either update your question to match the answer you accepted or un-accept the answer. It does not satisfy your requirement that **the string may vary**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use positive lookahead. Here is the regex which works for your case.

```
let temp = 'Hi {{username}}, Your request with request id: {{requestId}} has been processed. Please contact your nearest shop.'
temp.match(/(?<={{)(\w+)(?=}})/g)
```

Comment: Great! It works

Comment: This won't match if there are whitespaces in the string in the brackets.

Comment: @jrook The main task here is to avoid getting the curly braces in the final matches. Everything else can be adjusted as needed by the OP.

Comment: You can use `/(?<={{\s*)[\w\$]+(?=\s*}})/g` as a more comprehensive check that will extract any reasonable variable names, even if there is whitespace around them.

Comment: @Kritarth The OP states (in bold font) that the string inside those brackets **may vary**. Your solution simply does not satisfy that requirement. Even if it works for the OP, it does not change the fact that this is a wrong answer to the question asked.

Comment: And it is not just whitespaces. Characters such as `|` , `$` , or `-` will break this regex. `$` is a valid character in JavaScript variable name.

Comment: @jrook The main goal was to extract the string present inside {{ }} and the solution is correct except the fact mentioned by you about the whitespace